# Error creating resource: [message] fopen(): Unable to find the wrapper

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api

I'm testing out GAE with a simple Google Books API but I cannot get it to work. Authentication works with oauth2, but I still cannot get past this error message:

```
" Error creating resource: [message] fopen(): Unable to find the wrapper &quot;https&quot; - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?"
```

I am following the Documentation. This is my PHP code:

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = ./gtmdocx-73165ebdfb29.json');
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("My Application");
        $client->setDeveloperKey("AIzaSyD******************");
        $client->setHttpClient(new GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false]));
        $service = new Google_Service_Books($client);

        $optParams = array('filter' => 'free-ebooks');
        $results = $service->volumes->listVolumes('Henry David Thoreau', $optParams);

        foreach ($results as $item) {
            echo $item['volumeInfo']['title'], "<br /> \n";
        }
```

I am using GuzzleHttp and this is hosted in Google App Engine. Should https or SSL be activated in GAE?

This is my php.ini:

```
google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = "1"
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_sapi_name"
extension = "php_curl.dll"
extension=curl.so
```